# Powershell Switch Parameter to add to end of expression

Tags: powershell

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
param([Switch]$myparameter)
If($myparamter -eq $true) {$export = Export-CSV c:\temp\temp.csv}
Get-MyFunction | $export
```

If $myparameter is passed, export the data to said location. Else, just display the normal output (in other words, ignore the $export). What doesn't work here is setting $export to the "Export-csv...". Wrapping it in quotes does not work.

I'm trying to avoid an if, then statement saying "if it's passed, export this. If it's not passed, output data"

I have a larger module that everything works in so there is a reason behind why I am looking to do it this way. Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

```
param([Switch] $myparameter)

# Define the core command as a *script block* (enclosed in { ... }),
# to be invoked later, either with operator . (no child variable scope) 
# or & (with child variable scope)
$scriptBlock = { Get-MyFunction }

# Invoke the script block with . (or &), and pipe it to the Export-Csv cmdlet,
# if requested.
If ($myparameter) { # short for: ($myparameter -eq $True), because $myparameter is a switch
  . $scriptBlock | Export-Csv c:\temp\temp.csv
} else {
  . $scriptBlock
}
```

---

[TessellatingHeckler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46290138/45375) is concise, works, and uses a number of advanced features cleverly - however, while it avoids an `if` statement, as requested, doing so may not yield the best or most readable solution in this case.

What you're looking for is to store a command *in a variable* for *later* execution, but your own attempt to do so:

```
If ($myparameter -eq $true) { $export = Export-CSV c:\temp\temp.csv }
```

results in *immediate* execution, which is not only unintended, but fails, because the `Export-Csv` cmdlet is missing input in the above statement.

You can store a snippet of source code for later execution in a variable via a *script block*, simply by enclosing the snippet in `{ ... }`, which in your case would mean:
`If ($myparameter -eq $true) { $export = { Export-Csv c:\temp\temp.csv } }`

<sup>Note that what you pass to `if` is itself a script block, but it is by definition one that is executed as soon as the `if` condition is found to be true.</sup>

A variable containing a script block can then be invoked on demand, using one of two operators:

- `.`, the "dot-sourcing" operator, which executes the script block in the current scope.
- `&`, the call operator, which executes the script block in a *child* scope with respect to potential variable definitions.

However, given that you only need the pipeline with an additional command if switch `$myparameter` is specified, it's better to change the logic:

- Store the shared core command, `Get-MyFunction`, in a script block, in variable `$scriptBlock`.
- Invoke that script block in an `if` statement, either standalone (by default), or by piping it to `Export-Csv` (if `-MyParameter` was specified).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to avoid an if, then statement

Uh, if you insist...

```
param([Switch]$myparameter)

$cmdlet, $params = (('Write-output', @{}), 
                    ('Export-Csv', @{'LiteralPath'='c:\temp\temp.csv'}))[$myparameter]

Get-MyFunction | & $cmdlet @params
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to get this working. Is there an article that you would be able to link me to learning more about the syntax? I have never seen this way before. Note, I am on PowerShell 5.0. And also, thank you very much.

Comment: @MattRemis which syntax? `&` is ['call operator'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators), it runs a command from a string. `$x, $y = @(1,2)` is variable assignment but doesn't seem well known that it can unpack a collection. `($a, $b)[]` is array index [abused to replace `if`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79895/571), relies on the paramter implicitly cast to [int] as 0/1. `$var = @{}; cmd @var` is [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

Comment: @MattRemis I've never seen it put together like this either, I made it up. And wouldn't really recommend it, although it is quite pleasing that it technically avoids `if`. But why would you want to avoid `if`? @mklement0's answer is a lot more sensible, and straightforward...